# where to place downloaded images when creating a gem

Tags: ruby, image, download, rubygems, bundle

I am creating a gem that it should download between 2 and 3 images from the internet. Where would be the best place to add it?

I did some research but found anything related to this topic. My first idea was to add it inside ~/.gem_images/, but I realised it can be quite intrusive to store the images there.

Then I thought to create a folder inside my gem structure called img/. The problem Is that I cannot know where is placed the gem each time I execute it. I don't know either where the specific code of the gem is placed (maybe it changes depending on the ruby manager?)

So I am not sure what to do, where would you place a folder that will contain a few images that a gem is generating?

Comment: are they static or something generated from the gem?

Comment: They will be automatically downloaded from internet. So they won't be static all time

Comment: I think the best thing to do would be to make this configurable by the user. That way whoever uses the gem can decide for themself.

Comment: The idea is to exec a bin in the CLI. For example `my_gem` and then this commands go to the internet and download an image. The user shouldn't do anything else than run this bin

Comment: I am thinking just to add it inside ~/downloads, if a better solution comes up, is more than welcome :). Just that User shouldn't notice about the downloading of this picture ( it will be a temporary picture and is totally unrelated to a rails project or sth like this). So my best to do it not intrusive is just put it there and if at some moment wants to delete it, feel free to do it...